# How to override the default eventlistener in a singular select element to make it behave like a multiple?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make it possible in a "normal" html select element to pick more than one option.

And yes: I know that there's an attribute for the select element called "multiple" which makes this possible by creating a scrollable list with a customizable height.

However, this is not what I'm looking for. I don't want a scrollable list, but rather the drop-down list of a "singular" select to show up when activated and then one should be able to pick multiple option with ctrl button pressed down. Ideally, the drop-down list should disappear when one disengages the ctrl button.

Is there some way of overriding the default eventlistener to make a behaviour like this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<select id="varSel" name="varSel">
  <option value="1">Variable 1</option>
  <option value="2">Variable 2</option>
  <option value="3">Variable 3</option>
  <option value="4">Variable 4</option>
  <option value="5">Variable 5</option>
</select>

<script>

let varSelector = document.getElementById("varSel");
var str = "";
var choices = [];

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(event)
                               {
    const key = event.key;
    
    if(key === "Control"){
        
        str = "ctrlDown"
        
    }
    
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(event)
                               {
    const key = event.key;
    
    if(key === "Control"){
        
        str = "ctrlUp"
        
    }
    
});

varSelector.addEventListener("change", function() {

    var v = varSel.value;

    if(str === "ctrlDown"){
        choices.push(v);
        console.log(choices);
    
     /* Here I need some code to keep all the previous selected options
     marked and prevent the drop-down list from hiding after selecting */
        
    }
    else{       
        choices = [v];
        console.log(choices[0]);
    }
    
    event.preventDefault();
  
}, false);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help or advice is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest a different approach? You can still use the `multiple` attribute and add event listeners for the `focus` and `blur` events, which will modify the `size` attribute:

```js
const mySelect = document.querySelector('#varSel');

mySelect.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  const options = mySelect.querySelectorAll('option');
  mySelect.setAttribute('size', options.length);
});

mySelect.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  mySelect.setAttribute('size', 1);
})
```

```html
<select id="varSel" name="varSel" size="1" multiple>
  <option value="1">Variable 1</option>
  <option value="2">Variable 2</option>
  <option value="3">Variable 3</option>
  <option value="4">Variable 4</option>
  <option value="5">Variable 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Very nice idea, thank you!! :) I might stick with that. However: when the size of a "multiple" is only 1, the arrows to the right stick out and it doesn't look very nice. Any ideas to minimize the arrows or make them "fit"?

Comment: I am afraid the scrollbar cannot easily and reliably be styled. You can try using the CSS `::-webkit-scrollbar-button` (see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) for details), but it is not supported by all browsers, or you can entirely remove the scrollbar with `#varSel { overflow-y: hidden; }`, but I would advise against it because it would have a bad impact on accessibility.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a bit of it and found this solution which hides the bottom arrow:

#varSel { 
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden; 
}

It's true that it removes the scrollbar, but I don't see that as a problem, since users can still click to see the list. And it's supported by most "modern" browsers so I feel quite safe using it. What bad impact on accessibility did you have in mind?

Comment: Sorry, my code went missing :) now it's there.

Comment: I think the main problem with that solution is that removing the scrollbars makes it harder to identify the element as something you can interact with. People have established expectations about how each element should look like; removing scrollbars might make harder to identify the element as a multi-select, so users might be unable to realize what to do with it (especially users with a more or less severe learning disability). You designed the interface so everything is clear to you, but you should try to look at it from the point of view of someone who is seeing it for the first time

Comment: P.S. sorry about the long comment but I am pretty passionate about the topic of usability and accessibility... :P

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. I'll take that into consideration. And no problem :) very happy to get help from someone who's passionate about what they're doing.